# How to parse ini files and choose appropriate function with python

Tags: python, function, parsing, ini

I try to use an ini file to configure the resolution to use in my script and need help to know how to do this.

"Fontion script":

```
    #RECUP QUALITE FHD
import re, os
def FHD(RFHD):
    mykey = open("/home/gaaara/adn/tmp/ajax.json", "r")
    for text in mykey:
        match = re.search('"FHD":"(.+?).mp4', text)
    if match:

        s = 'http://www.website.fr:1935/' + match.group(1) + '.mp4?audioindex=0.smil'


    return  s
```

In fact it has 2 other similar functions in the file `HD` and `SD` which are the others function of resolution. How do I programmatically select the right function?

Edit

```
import ConfigParser
import sys
sys.path.append('files/')
from xrez import FHD
from xrez import HD
from xrez import SD
#variables
x1080 = FHD('RFHD')
x720 = HD('RHD')
x480 = SD('RSD')
#fin

config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')
try:
    val = config.get('resolution', 'Write the resolution wish', 'x1080' , 'x720' , 'x480' )
except:
    sys.exit(1)

print val
```

Comment: Are you trying to parse "INI" or "JSON" files?

Comment: i want to parse ini files to configure the resolution to use in my script sorry I badly translated your question ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

some ini file like that:

> [section1]
>   var1=value1

Would be read by that:

```
import ConfigParser

config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config.read('conf.ini')

try:
    val = config.get('section1', 'var1')
except:
    sys.exit(1)

print val
```

Comment: ty for your demo I go and look at it

Comment: i use your demo juste how to inset my variable and use the variable is Writing in the ini files ?

Comment: I recommend you take a look at https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html the `examples` section at the bottom. To set a value, it is very easy just do `config.set('section1', 'var1', '1024')` where 1024 would be the value you want to write. Then when you read, you can also use `getint` instead of `get`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Python [ConfigParser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html) library.  This will read your INI file and give you the parameters you need (e.g. resolution), which you can then use in your JSON downloading code.

Comment: Try `{'Write the resolution wish': [1080,720,480]}`. You were missing the brackets [].

Comment: error  File `"/home/gaaara/adn/files/test3.py", line 7
    1080 = FHD('RFHD')
SyntaxError: can't assign to literal`

Comment: Right, you cannot have variable names that start with numbers.  Try `x1080` or something.

Comment: You seem to be asking new questions several times now.  We can't just go back and forth writing your program one line at a time.

Comment: mm yes i post 3 question just is a function different I really try to write the code myself but I am one begin